# What degenerate cases are handled by swapping the pivot to the front in Hoare's partition?

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I looked at the post by Brian Bi: https://spin0r.wordpress.com/2021/01/01/how-exactly-to-do-linear-time-quickselect-with-duplicate-elements

It has an example implementation of Hoare's partition:

```
// let x be the initial value of *pivot and k the return value; then,
// [begin, k) <= x and [k, end) >= x
template <std::random_access_iterator It>
It partition(It begin, It pivot, It end) {
    using std::ranges::iter_swap;
    iter_swap(begin, pivot);
    It i = begin;
    It j = end;
    while (true) {
        do {
            --j;
        } while (*j > *pivot);
        while (*i < *pivot) {
            ++i;
        }
        if (i < j) {
            iter_swap(i, j);
            ++i;
        } else {
            return j + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

He writes that:

> except for the initial swap to move the pivot to the front, which is necessary in order to avoid degenerate partitions

What degenerate cases/partitions does he imply?

This implementation is quite hard for me to understand, as it doesn't use a fixed pivot, and uses a combination of while/do-while; I guess hence the confusion.

By the way, trying this code in the following setup:

```
void print(const int *a, const size_t len) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 13, 3, 19, 5, 15, 24, 23, 9, 17, 11, 21, 7, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 0};
    constexpr auto size = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    print(a, size);

    std::cout << a[12] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Element count in the 1st partition: " << partition(a, a + 12, std::end(a)) - a << std::endl;
    print(a, size);
}
```

gives this

```
1 13 3 19 5 15 24 23 9 17 11 21 7 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 0 
7
Element count in the 1st partition: 6
0 1 3 11 5 9 24 23 15 17 19 21 13 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 7
```

Is it ok? I thought partitioning on 7 should bring 2/4/6 etc. to the left of it; shouldn't they?..

Comment: The swap prevents the partition from dropping into the worst case if the partition comes pre-sorted. Swap the elements around and the sorted partition is no longer sorted.

Comment: If you want clarification, contact the author.

Comment: The code shown is just plain broken: it produces [incorrect result](https://godbolt.org/z/8KrGr1jhK). Removing that initial `iter_swap` makes it produce [correct result](https://godbolt.org/z/hevdYbdfa) (at least on my tiny example; I'm not yet sure it's correct in general).

Comment: No, it's broken [with](https://godbolt.org/z/dYGfTcM5v) or [without](https://godbolt.org/z/hKebGxc8v) that `iter_swap`